# In SQL, why are user profiles usually done with 2 separate tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am learning SQL (coming from NoSQL so it's been hard to adapt), and after looking up example models, I am finding the case that many of them use 2 separate tables for basic user info (which contains things like username and password) and profile info.

Is there a specific reason for doing so? I don't see why you couldn't do something like this using one table?

```
user
---
id
username
password
birthdate
avatar
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You technically can but I would guess its because you want to keep the user's private data seperate from the users additional info. Its a little bit more cleaner I feel.

Comment: You should have a look at the rules of Codd. He describes the rules for designing RDBMS (which is very different from you NoSQL) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs for an example if your are using BLOB data to store a profile picture or something related it is better to stored separately for performance reasons.